Constant errors with .cshtml files, but project builds successfully
My project is a solution with ASP.NET MVC Visual studio 2019.
I have quite a weird deal, I have a fully buildable and runnable project, but in visual studio I get constant errors especially in my .cshtml files.

If I do build the project, it goes back to 0 errors for a couple seconds, before returning to the long list of errors.
Generally my controller files have no errors, but .cshtml is a different story.
I have tried:

Unloading and reloading the project
Closing visual studio and reopening
Restarting my computer and reloading the solution.
Obviously building/cleaning solution

Any help? Not a deal breaker but incredibly annoying.

You can try manually deleting the bin/debug folders

I tried this, and still showing 116 errors. So annoying!

Regarding the two errors (CS1980 and CS1660) displayed in your screenshot, you can refer to these methods:

Try adding the following namespace:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

Check this option:


Close Visual Studio and delete the .vs folder in the solution directory. This folder is hidden. You may need to enable the option to show hidden files in File Explorer.


